# Хочу подключить таблицу access в C# , но выбивает ошибку

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для Form.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Form : Window
    {
        public Form()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Дима.accdb;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database ");

            con.Open();

            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Мобільні телефони ", con);
            OleDbCommandBuilder cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "Мобільні телефони");
            DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();

            dg.ItemsSource = ds.Tables["Мобільні телефони"].DefaultView;
            con.Close();

        }

        private void button8_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void dataGrid1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: "select * from [Мобільні телефони]"

Comment: [mcve] и описание ошибки.